# Google (YouTube) Auth API

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use the Google Auth Python library to perform OAuth2 into my own YouTube account, so I can gather metrics of my own subscriptions.  The code, however, isn't working.

I have setup a service account, and that process created a "Compatible OAuth2" client, and I exported the JSON key file from that.  I have also setup an API key, which is also enabled to do all the things (yes, I know, the sec-eng soul inside you is dying) ...

Here is the code:

```
# Python 3.10.0

from google.oauth2 import service_account

import requests
import json
import os

# Start an OAuth session
service_account_info = json.load(open(f'{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/.config/service_account.json'))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)

# API Key
with open(f'{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/.config/.apikey') as f:
    API_KEY = f.read()

HEADERS = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials}'}

# Construct the URL
URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions'

# Parameters
PARAMS = {'part':'id', 'maxResults':'250', 'order':'alphabetical', 'mine':'true', 'key': API_KEY}

# Make the request
request = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, params=PARAMS)
response = request.json()

# Print the response
print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "location": "Authorization",
                "locationType": "header"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

I'm fairly confident that the problem is in how I'm handling the `credentials` but I don't know how that is supposed to go.

I appreciate your input and help.

All I'm trying to do is list my own YouTube Channel Subscriptions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube data api does not support service account authentication to standard YouTube accounts. hense the `OAuth 2 access token` in the error message.

> Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

## rumor

I have heard that it does work with google workspace domain YouTube accounts because then you can configure the domain wide delegation.  I have not tried

## Other options

You can use standard oauth2 and authorize your application once.  Store the refresh token and then your application can then just use the refresh token to request a new access token as needed.  Just remember to set your application in production or your refresh token will expire after seven days and you will need to authorize the application again.